# TypeScript: Type alias for function signature not as strict as direct annotations

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to simplyfy signatures in TypeScript using a type alias:

```
interface State {
  value: string;
  error: string;
}

type Reducer = (value: string) => (state: State) => State;

const setValue: Reducer = value => state => ({
  ...state,
  value,
  unknownProperty: "Hello"
});
```

I would expect this to fail since I'm trying to set a property that doesn't exist.

When I do this, it does fail:

```
const setValue2 = (value: string) => (state: State): State => ({
  ...state,
  value,
  unknownProperty: "Hello"
});
```

with error message: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'unknownProperty' does not exist in type 'State'`, which is what I want.

What is the difference? Why does one compile, but the other not? How can I enforce type safety like the second example using a separate definition like in the first example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case the produced function type (implicitly resolved) is [compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) with type `Reducer`. Have a look at this example:

```
let x = () => ({name: "Alice"});
let y = () => ({name: "Alice", location: "Seattle"});

x = y; // OK
```

However in the second case the return type is explicitly specified `(state: State): State`, here *"Object literal may only specify known properties"* comes into play

Comment: Thanks for answering. Does that mean there isn't any way to strictly enfore a function signature like in my first example? It might not seem like a big deal, but since I'm already spreading the previous state into the result, I'm not protected from mispelling.

Comment: Well, not that I'm aware of. If there's I'd also like to know :)